# Trying to get to a long url using system("firefox longURL") in linux

Tags: url, firefox, terminal, command-line-arguments

Every time I try to open firefox using the system function and a long url, only part of the URL gets placed in the address bar. For example,

```
system("firefox www.yellowpages.com/whitepages/address?street=1234+12th+St.&zip=1234&state=AB");
```

Only places part of the URL into the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

The execvp function works perfectly, so I am going to use that instead.